# Handling Group4 TIFF images in python

Tags: python, tiff, libtiff

PIL doesn't natively support G4 images, is there some other python package that does?  I need to read multi-page TIFF images and pull convert them into gif/png on the fly to serve up in a web page.  (I'm not converting them all on the fly, but cherry picking them for display).

I've considered using ImageMagick which has that conversion ability, but I'd like to be able to reach into the TIFF files and see what is inside them for indexing.

Comment: This question is about 2 years old now and the Python Pillow package is available.  Use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this post about a patch against PIL](https://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2010/4/15/133252/616), [this project to wrap FreeImage](http://freeimagepy.sourceforge.net/), and [this project to wrap libtiff](http://www.haynold.com/software_projects/2004/pytiff/).

Comment: The PIL patch works and since I already have PIL loaded in my Django project, it seems to be the one to go with.

Comment: This was easy to fix in linux, but doing in windows (and in a VirtualENV to boot) nearly impossible to get working.  I finally got all the compile issues solved, and have pushed the code to https://github.com/mark0978/PIL-withG4 feel free to use it.  This will build/install on linux or on windows (and in virtualENVs).  Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: You should let the PIL people know about that!

Comment: I will, but this patch I used has been around since 2005, don't hold your breath.  It uses some of the tiff private headers to work which would probably be a problem if tiff wasn't such an old format that the code fairly mature  The libTiff code I used was from 2007 (3.8.2).  I just looked and there is now a 4.0 that changes some of those files, but nothing that will affect this patch.

Answer (score 1):

Using [PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/):

```
from PythonMagick import Image
Image('CCITT_4.TIF[0]').write("PNG8:CCITT_4.PNG")
```