# Using TIFF G4 image in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I wrote a pure python TIFF G4 decompress for use with `tifffile.py`. I know there are ways to add `libtiff` to a custom PIL, but I never could get that working very well in a mixed virtualenv.  I want to manipulate the image in PIL. I am looking for pointers in hooking my decompressor to stock PIL for `TiffImagePlugin.py`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using [Pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) in a virtualenv? It works really well, even with TIFF.

Comment: It does, but it still doesn't work with Tiff compressed with group 4.  Does pillow allowing hooking in additional decompressors?

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7034015/624900)?

Comment: Yes.  I can uncompress the image, which was their question.  I am looking to hook my code into stock PIL to add it as a valid decompressor if possible.

Comment: Have you read [Writing Your Own File Decoder](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/decoder.htm)?

Comment: Yes, but it seems to cover a whole new image type, ie image type 'foo'.  The decoders appear to be working off the extension of the file name.  The TiffImagePlugin would still handle the G4 compressed image and be unable to process it.  That is why I starting using tifffile.py.  For that, I only needed to add 'ccittfax4' to the TIF_DECOMPESSORS.  TiffImagePlugin doesn't seem to allow a clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `TiffImagePlugin` does not easily allow me to hook in additional decompressors.  Replacing `TiffImageFile._decoder` with a dictionary of decoders might work, but you would have to examine and test each release of PIL to ensure it hasn't broken.  This level of maintenance is just as bad as a custom PIL.  I appreciate the design of `tifffile.py` for using a dictionary of decoders.  It made it very easy.

Final solution?  I couldn't hook my code into PIL.  I had to use `PIL.Image.fromarray()` to using my decompressed images.