# PIL group4 decoder not found

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I've installed PIL 1.1.7 with the [windows installer for Python 2.7](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm) and I'm trying to use it to open a `TIFF` file. However, I keep receiving `IOError: decoder group4 not available`.

What bit is missing? To my understanding, the necessary libs should be compiled in.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034015/handling-group4-tiff-images-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868963/using-tiff-g4-image-in-pil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIL 1.1.7 can not read G4 TIFF files. There are unofficial [patches](https://github.com/wiredfool/Python-Imaging-Library-G4-Tiff-Support) and [binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil) that can.

Update: [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) 2.x can read G4 TIFF files.

Comment: Hmm, the docs say it can open tiff files. What's the difference between that and G4 tiff?

Comment: G4 (CCITT T.6) is just one of many possible compression schemes found in TIFF. Not all compression schemes are supported by all TIFF readers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#TIFF_Compression_Tag.